# How to write section around desired string of a log file into a new file?

Tags: logging, awk, sed, grep

I need to search a log file for a string and write the whole section of the log before the string till a timestamp. Is there a way this can be done? I was finding either timestamp based or string based but not both.

This is how my log looks:

```
*05-24@08:38:31 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = **47839738**
        AttributeCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeCallUuid [str] = "00VR1R7O1SBJFB0ETLD698LAES005RVR"
05-24@08:38:41 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
        AttributePropagatedCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeUserData [bstr] = KVList:
'IW_CaseUid' [str] = "bd6d7141-1bc5-4b5e-ae53-6715ca72a3d0"
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = 47839739
        AttributeCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeCallUuid [str] = "00VR1R7O1SBJFB0ETLD698LAES005RVR"
05-24@08:38:46 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
        AttributePropagatedCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeUserData [bstr] = KVList:
'IW_CaseUid' [str] = "bd6d7141-1bc5-4b5e-ae53-6715ca72a3d0"
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = 47839740
        AttributeCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeCallUuid [str] = "00VR1R7O1SBJFB0ETLD698LAES005RVR"
05-24@08:38:51 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
        AttributePropagatedCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeUserData [bstr] = KVList:
'IW_CaseUid' [str] = "bd6d7141-1bc5-4b5e-ae53-6715ca72a3d0"
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = **47839738**
        AttributeCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeCallUuid [str] = "00VR1R7O1SBJFB0ETLD698LAES005RVR"*
```

If I search for 47839738 I wish to have whatever is before 47839738 in the log in a new file till it reaches timestamp MM-DD@HH:MM:SS and keep searching throughout the file. In this example the desired output would look like:

```
*05-24@08:38:31 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = **47839738**
05-24@08:38:51 TRACE (Server.java:854)     - svdctmpe -> 'EventReleased' (65) attributes:
        AttributeConnID [long] = 08b0028321e5d6fb
        AttributePropagatedCallType [int] = 3 [Outbound]
        AttributeUserData [bstr] = KVList:
'IW_CaseUid' [str] = "bd6d7141-1bc5-4b5e-ae53-6715ca72a3d0"
'IW_BundleUid' [str] = "e79d5c11-ce97-408a-a94b-da6c99036ee0"
'ecda_OBNum' [str] = "7278672448"
        AttributeCallID [int] = **47839738***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Regex (Regular Expressions) to find all occurrences of log entries that contain "47839738" that are delimited by the date formatting (example "05-24@08:38").

Here is the java code, where `input` would be your log file as a string:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String input = "";
        try
        {
            input = readFile("c:\\temp\\regex.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(input);

        Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?:(?!(\\n\\d\\d-\\d\\d@\\d\\d:\\d\\d))[\\s\\S])*47839738()(?:(?!(\\d\\d-\\d\\d@\\d\\d:\\d\\d))[\\s\\S])*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find())
        {
            java.lang.System.out.println(m.group());
        }



    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)  throws IOException 
    {
      byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
      return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
}
```

Each `m.group()` would contain a separate entry from the log that contains the key term "47839738".

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but my log files are huge in size, around 40 MB each. Would you suggest a similar approach to have a whole file as an input and then write the output to a different file?

Comment: Yes, you could read in the whole file as a string and then append each match into a new file.  However, I am not sure what the performance would be like with file as large as 40 MB.

Comment: Do you mean copy the content in the 40MB file and pass it as a string in place of "input"?

Comment: No, I would open the file and read it in.  I am updating the code above to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var=`grep -nr "47839738 " log.log | cut -d ":" -f 1`; head -n $var log.log  | grep "MM-DD@HH:MM:SS " -A $var
```

1. First get the line number were 47839738  appears
2. Then get all lines
   from beginning to that line
3. Then get all the lines from date to that
       line

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but my log files always have repetitive entries. Would you suggest a similar approach for finding repetitive entries and then writing them to a different file?